# JavaScript Username authentication

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, authentication

The following represent my registration link which lead to open a modal:

```
<a href="#registermodal" data-toggle="modal">Register Here</a>
```

The following represents the code for my modal dialog:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="registermodal" role="dialog" style="overflow: scroll;">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" name="f2" id="regisform" method="post" onsubmit="return false;" role="form">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4>Registration<button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body"> 
                <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputusername3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                    <input type="text" name="txtusername" class="form-control" id="inputusername3" placeholder="username">
                                </div>
                            </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">   
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="regisBtn" class="btn btn-primary" value="Registration">
                            <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
</form>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
```

The below represent the JavaScript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#regisBtn").click(function(){
var username1=$("#inputusername3").val();
$.post("registercheck.php", {username:username1}, function(result){
if(result==='true')
alert("true");
else
alert("false");
});
});
});
```

The below represent my php code:

```
<?php
$username1=$_POST['username'];
$con= mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("onlineshop",$con);
$query1= mysql_query("select username from users where username=$username1",$con);
if(mysql_num_rows($query1)==1){
    echo 'false';
}else{
mysql_query("insert into users(username)values ('".$username1."')",$con);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username']=$username1;
    echo 'true';
}
```

There is error in mysqli_num_rows() shows that it expects parameter 1 to be resource, Boolean given in something like that
I dont knw why my code is not working. please help me with my code to check whether the username is exists or not?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Try to log the result with console.log(result); to see what is happening

Comment: need to prevent default submit or page will reload before ajax is done

Comment: There is error like mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, Boolean given in..

Comment: Ans me practically if possible

Comment: There is an error in query execution. Try to log that using echo mysql_error() after mysql_query()

Comment: There is error in mysql_num_rows() shows that it expects parameter 1 to be resource, Boolean given in something like that

Answer (score 1):

You have 4 problems with your code.  First, you are using `mysql_*` functions.  Use `mysqli_*` instead, `mysql_*` is deprecated.  Second, you are vulnerable to SQL injection.  This is fixed below by using `mysqli_real_escape_string`.  Consider using PDO instead.  Third, your `select` query is malformed - any string in the query must be wrapped in single quotes.  Fourth, in a couple of `mysql_*` function calls, your database link is the last parameter.  It should always be the first parameter in the call.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($con, "onlineshop");

$clean_username1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);

$query1 = mysqli_query($con, "select username from users where username = '".$clean_username1."'");

if (mysqli_num_rows($query1) == 1){
    echo 'false';
} else {
    mysqli_query($con, "insert into users (username) values ('".$clean_username1."')");

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    echo 'true';
}
```

Comment: There is error in mysqli_num_rows() shows that it expects parameter 1 to be resource, Boolean given in something like that

Comment: Does your root user have a password?  Is the MySQL server on the same machine?  Does the database 'onlineshop' exist?  Does the 'users' table exist in the 'onlineshop' database?  Is 'username' a valid field in the 'users' table?  That error means that something in MySQL is preventing the query from running, so it returns false.

Comment: Also, I didn't state this explicitly in my answer but the code I included had all 4 issues fixed.  Not sure if you tried it since I didn't mention that.